# problem with the payload when saving a record

Tags: dynamics-crm, odata, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

when I try to add\change the value of a custom lookup and then save it, I get this error:

```
Exception Message: Error identified in Payload provided by the user for Entity :'', For more information on this error please follow this help link https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2195293  ---->  InnerException : Microsoft.OData.ODataException: An undeclared property 'ey_org_unit_hr_id' which only has property annotations in the payload but no property value was found in the payload. In OData, only declared navigation properties and declared named streams can be represented as properties without values.
   at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightResourceDeserializer.ReadUndeclaredProperty(IODataJsonLightReaderResourceState resourceState, String propertyName, Boolean propertyWithValue)
   at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightResourceDeserializer.ReadPropertyWithoutValue(IODataJsonLightReaderResourceState resourceState, String propertyName)
   at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightResourceDeserializer.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<ReadResourceContent>b__0(PropertyParsingResult propertyParsingResult, String propertyName)
   at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightDeserializer.ProcessProperty(PropertyAndAnnotationCollector propertyAndAnnotationCollector, Func`2 readPropertyAnnotationValue, Action`2 handleProperty)
   at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightResourceDeserializer.ReadResourceContent(IODataJsonLightReaderResourceState resourceState)
   at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightReader.StartReadingResource()
   at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightReader.ReadResourceSetItemStart(PropertyAndAnnotationCollector propertyAndAnnotationCollector, SelectedPropertiesNode selectedProperties)
   at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightReader.ReadAtStartImplementationSynchronously(PropertyAndAnnotationCollector propertyAndAnnotationCollector)
   at Microsoft.OData.ODataReaderCore.ReadImplementation()
   at Microsoft.OData.ODataReaderCore.InterceptException[T](Func`1 action)
   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.ODataReaderExtensions.ReadResourceOrResourceSet(ODataReader reader)
   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.ODataResourceDeserializer.Read(ODataMessageReader messageReader, Type type, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)
   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStream(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger).

ErrorCode: -2147185383
HexErrorCode: 0x80048d19
```

the field's logical and schema name is "ey_org_unit_hr_id" (both of them are identical).

I opened the post request that the form sends and this is what I found:

```
{"ey_org_unit_hr_id@odata.bind":"/ey_businessunits(91293b20-afb7-e611-bec8-0050568c00dc)",
"ey_org_unit_hr_id@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue":null,
"ey_s_name":"test555",
"ey_b_is_doctor_house":false,
"ey_b_is_route_service_requests":false,
"ey_b_real_branch":false,
"statuscode":1,
"statecode":0}
```

then I opened the metadata and found out that the NavigationalProperty Name of this field is different than what is used in the post request (ey_org_unit_hr_id is used in the request but the navigational property name is ey_ey_businessunit_ey_branch_hr which is also the name of the relationship).

[Photo of the navigation property name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57uHN.png)

so i tried to send a post request using postman whith the currect NavigationProperty Name and it worked without an error.
Here is the request:

```
{"ey_ey_businessunit_ey_branch_hr@odata.bind":"/ey_businessunits(91293b20-afb7-e611-bec8-0050568c00dc)",
"ey_ey_businessunit_ey_branch_hr@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue":null,
"ey_s_name":"test555",
"ey_b_is_doctor_house":false,
"ey_b_is_route_service_requests":false,
"ey_b_real_branch":false,
"statuscode":1,
"statecode":0}
```

I thought about changing the navigational property name to what is used in the original post request but I don't know if I can change the metadata.

Comment: lookups use the navigation property, not the logical name, you can use my tool Dataverse REST Builder https://github.com/GuidoPreite/DRB to generate the request

Comment: @GuidoPreite yes but for some reason, the form sends the request with the logical name instead of the navigation property name.

Comment: which form? who created the form? you can update the source code of the form?

Answer (score 1):

You should check your error code at the below link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/reference/web-service-error-codes

AFAIK, the 0x80048d19 code will be exposed by sending request with invalid data.
In my case, I got this error code when i sent request without header "Content-Type: application/json"

I hope this can be helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

Try this property name: `_ey_org_unit_hr_id_value`.

Comment: doesn't work.
my problem is that the form is sending the request using the logical name instead of the navigation property name